# 开 and 给 as Result Complement

Tags: grammar, usage, result-complement

My textbook introduces 开 and 给 as **Result Complements** which are placed after verbs to indicate the result of actions. However, the book doesn’t provide any examples.

Can you guys teach me how to use the Result Complements, and provide some examples too?

非常感谢你们！

Comment: 把 + sth + 给 + sb: return / send / give sth to sb. verb + 开 + sb/sth: do the verb to make sb/sth be opened by the subject, do the verb to make sb/sth to get out of the subject, do the verb to make sb/sth away from of the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Result complement follow a single character verb to provide 'result' of the verb

Example of 开 as result complement:

跑 = run

跑(开) = run (and get away)

~

放 = release

放(开) = release (let out)

~

拆 = break

拆(开) = break (open)

Example of 给 as result complement:

供 = provide

供(给) = provide (and give)

~

補 = replenish

補(给) = replenish (and give)

Comment: In 卖给我, would 给 not be considered a result complement?

Comment: @Buddy L 给 in 卖给我 (sell to me) means 'to'. It is not a result complement but a preposition

Comment: Is there a practical reason why it could not be described as a result complement here?

Comment: 给 is the result of 供 or 補  but 给 in 卖给+n (sell to +n) is not a result.It is a preposition  that indicates to whom the action is directed to

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't answer my question. Is there a practical reason? If I define 给 as a result complement here, is my definition going to run into problems elsewhere in the language? For example 见 is a result complement of 看, but 看见 can still take a noun as an object: 他看见我了. So as far as I can tell the ability to take a noun as an object doesn't mean that there is no result complement present.

Comment: @Buddy L -- 给 can be used as a result complement or as a preposition 'to', you have to look at the context. For example, 出 is the result complement of 卖出一輛車 (you sell a car, and it is out), but 给 in 卖给我 (sell to me) is a preposition. Although 给 in 補给一輛車 would be a result complement, it doesn't make logical sense. 给 can only be a result complement to a verb that can result in 'giving' like 供给 or 補给 (provide and resupply can be given, but sell can't) On the other hand 了 in 卖了我 is a result complement (you sell and finished selling me)

Answer (score 2):

To add on to the previous answer, even though both are classified as Result Complements, they differ in practical usage.

For example, ~开 often has an imperative tone to it, and does not include an object in the sentence.

> 走开！Go away!
>
> 放开！ Let go!

Indeed, there are other examples like 拆开 which aren’t imperative, but this 搭配 is very commonly used to order someone to do something.

On the other hand, ~给 is almost always followed by the object of the sentence.

For example:

> 交给他 (give it to him)
>
> 还给他 (return it to him)

If you didn’t put 他, the object, the phrases would respectively become “give it to” and “return it to”, which make no sense.

Answer (score 1):

For 开, I'd guess the most common is [离开](http://youdao.com/w/%E7%A6%BB%E5%BC%80) ("to leave") and [打开](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%89%93%E5%BC%80) ("open" or "start"):

> **离开**北京 (leave Beijing)
> **离开**女朋友 (leave girlfriend)
>
> **打开**电脑 (start the computer)
> **打开**窗户 (open the window) or 把窗户**打开**
> **打开**书包 (open the backpack)

but there's many others, such as:

> **张开**手 (open your hand) or 把手**张开**
> **展开**眼睛 (open your eyes)
> **放开**我 (release me [e.g. from your grip])
> **松开**腰带 (loosen your belt)
> **撕开**衣服 (tear open clothes) or 把衣服**撕开**
> **拉开**窗帘 (open the curtains) or 把窗帘**拉开**

It's possible to insert a 不 in the examples above (except for the `把...V开` examples) to indicate it's impossible.  E.g. **离不开**女朋友 (cannot leave girlfriend).

An example in the "real world":

> 67天没回家，女护士**打开**房门瞬间惊呆!<sup>[[src]](https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1664408411018799952&wfr=spider&for=pc)</sup>
> 67 days without returning home, female nurse **opens** [her] apartment door and is instantly stupefied.

Also 给 arises in several ways:

> **借给**钱 (lend money)
> **付给**司机100元 (pay the driver 100 yuan)
>
> 把图片**发给**我 (send me the pictures)
> 把钱**退给**我 (refund my money)
> 把我的东西**还给**我 (return my things)
> 把故事**写给**我 (write me a story)
>
> **传**电影**给**朋友 (transmit a movie to friends)
> **寄**信**给**她 (post a letter to her)
> **发**短信**给**他 (give him a text message)

There's also this structure where 给 comes first (which may not count as a "result complement", but it is closely related):

> **给**朋友**发**短信 (give your friend a text message)
> **给**你**送**礼物 (give you a present)

You'll see [传染](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BC%A0%E6%9F%93)给别人 ("spread to others" or "infect others") a lot in today's news:

> 故意**传染给别人**疾病违法吗?<sup>[[src]](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1238122212300687459.html)</sup>
> Is deliberately **infecting others** with disease illegal?